# WebScene: scene completely black in Chrome

Tags: arcgis-online, web-scene

We suddenly have problems visualizing ArcGIS Online WebScenes in Google Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and I am wondering if we are the only ones, as some searches returned not something like it. OS is Windows 7.

What we see is actually nothing in the scene frame:
[image]

We contacted ESRI's support but they did not seem to know about it. This is happening in both existing- and new scenes. Both local and global. It does work in IE (11.something) but we need it to work in Chrome.

Devtools shows a lot of errors like

> [.WebGL-0000000006BB1390] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Error: 0x00000502, in
>   ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/d3d/d3d9/Image9.cpp,
>   createSurface:278. Internal D3D9 error: HRESULT: 0x8876086C: Failed to
>   create image surface

**Update 20-08-2019:**
It turns out that the WebGL2 tests fail:

https://get.webgl.org/webgl2/

https://webglreport.com/?v=2

Comment: Can you go to https://get.webgl.org/ and do you see the spinning cube?

Comment: Hej @RussRoberts, I do see the spinning cube, but when visiting https://webglreport.com/?v=2 it shows "× This browser supports WebGL 2, but it is disabled or unavailable." Probably IT has 'updated' my video drivers as all was working before.

Comment: Are you using Windows7?
I'm experiencing the same in an interior design software when using a PC with Windows7 , but not with Windows10...

Comment: Windows 7 indeed. Strange thing tho it used to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the videocard drivers fixed my problem.

I did check the display adapters in the Device Manager for updates earlier but there were no updates available.

Now I checked with the vendors site and installed their latest critical update and the problem is gone.